# How to detect classes used only by deprecated methods or classes recursively?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

For example, i'd mark a method *hello()* as deprecated in eclipse, and that this method makes use of *class A and B* instances.

*Class A* is used in other classes and methods other than *hello()*, but *Class B* is exclusively used only in *hello()* method **as private or default package implementation class**.

Since *hello()* is now deprecated, it makes sense to me that *Class B* should be deprecated also, but **finding all these classes could proove to be a headache**.

Imagine there are *lots of other private implementation classes* used by this *hello()*.

Imagine *Class B* itself *have private classes that are only used in Class B*.

Imagine we deprecate **not a method**, but a class that could be **having lots of other private classes**.

How to find these *should-be-deprecated* classes **recursively**, so that i could deprecate them in eclipse ?

This kind of headache *could be prevented* by using *private nested classes*, but what if we're talking about *legacy codes* ?

Also i could just delete the method hello() and find unused classes. But i prefer deprecating the codes there with comments as i might be *undeprecate them later*.

Comment: [`@Deprecated` is usually used for the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html), not for internal code. If I understand you correctly, you also want to mark internal code as deprecated that is used exclusively by the deprecated API (and would be dead code if the deprecated API was removed), right?

Comment: hi @howlger, yes that is correct. I just realize about it's supposed to be used for public API. Basically changes happen in my code, rendering some parts irrelevant anymore. But rather than removing the irrelevants, i'd like to mark them as irrelevant with a specific id explicitly with reasons, but they'd still linger for a while before finally gets deleted. The deletion in the future should be easy as we can find the irrelevant codes marked with the same id.

Comment: I see. But how about to go for tests against the API with a good test coverage instead. When removing a deprecated API, the missing test coverage would show the dead code.

Comment: Thank you @howlger, i'll give it a good thought